# Override metho odoo 10 isn't working

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I need to override the create method in my model on odoo 10 :

in my module i have Three Models :

Asset With

```
validated = fields.Boolean("Is validated")
survey2_ids = fields.One2many('mymodule.survey2', 'asset_id', string='Survey2')
```

Survey2 with :

```
name = fields.Char()
asset_id = fields.Many2one('asset.asset', description='Asset')
survey1_id = fields.Many2one('mymodule.survey1', description="Survey1")
description = fields.Text(description="description")
```

Survey1 with :

```
name = fields.Char(description="Name")
ok = fields.Boolean("Is ok")
description = fields.Text()
```

The goal in here is when creating a new asset, and if validated = True: all records in mymodule.survey1 with ok==True should be copied in survey2_ids, i tried this function but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    survey1_ids = self.env['mymodule.survey1'].search([('ok', '=', True)])
    if self.validated:
        for rec in survey1_ids:
            vals['survey2_ids'] = [(0, False, {'asset_id': self.id, 'survey2_id': rec.id,'name':rec.name,'description':})]
    return super(asset_asset, self).create(vals)
```

Any help will be aappreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code :

1. Create is kind of a "class method" (it is tied to the model, no to the record). So when you ask for the value of `self.validated`, this will always be false because self is not the record you're creating, it's the model. You should check `vals.get('validated')` instead. Or create the record before-hand and use it instead of self (in my example, `res` in the newly created record).
2. You're not really copying survey 1 into survey 2. You just have to create survey 2 using the data in survey 1.

The solution that I think is best :

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    res = super(asset_asset, self).create(vals)
    if vals.get('validated'):
        survey1_ids = self.env['mymodule.survey1'].search([('ok', '=', True)])
        for s in survey1_ids:
            v = {
                'name': s.name,
                'description': s.description,
                'survey1_id': s.id,
                'asset_id': res.id
             }
             self.env['mymodule.survey2'].create(v)
     return res
```

Comment: it worked perfeectly!  thank you soo much for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are no errors in the logs, you are not getting what you intended to do. Once the code has executed, you are only getting 1 survey attached to the asset.

This is because inside the create function you wrote:

`vals['survey2_ids'] = [(0, False, {'asset_id': self.id, 'survey2_id': rec.id,'name':rec.name,'description':})]`

This will override the survey2_id in the vals each and every time in the for loop.

What you should do here is:

```
survey_2_list = []
for rec in survey1_ids:
    survey_2_list.append((0, False, {'asset_id': self.id, 'survey2_id': rec.id,'name':rec.name,'description':rec.description}))
vals['survey2_ids'] = survey_2_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    survey_2_list = []
    if self.validated:
        survey1_ids = self.env['mymodule.survey1'].search([('ok', '=', True)])
        if survey1_ids:
            for rec in survey1_ids:
                values = {
                    'asset_id': self.id, 
                    'survey2_id': rec.id,
                    'name':rec.name,
                    'description':rec.description,
                    }
                survey_2_list.append((0, False, values))
            vals['survey2_ids'] = survey_2_list
    return super(asset_asset, self).create(vals)
```